# Почему я могу менять тему дискорд сервера примерно 2 раза в час?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

У меня есть дискорд бот, который умеет менять тему канала (topic по-другому). Но почему-то он меняет тему канала лишь 2-5 раза в час. Что я делаю не так и как избавится от этой проблемы (хотя бы чтобы было тоже самое, но с >6000 раз в час)?

Вот код:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
import time

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/", help_command=None)
@client.command(name="test")
async def test(ctx):
    channel = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.channels, id=id of channel)
    await channel.edit(topic="0")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="1")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="2")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="3")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="4")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="5")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="6")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="7")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="8")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="9")
    time.sleep(1)
    await channel.edit(topic="10")
client.run("token")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В API Discord'а метод редактирования канала (названия и описания) с недавних пор имеет ограничение для ботов - 2 изменения в 10 минут.
[image: Сообщение от сотрудника Discord]

С этим ничего не сделать, можно только смириться и не менять заголовки каналов так часто.